# developing a django cms

Tags: python, django

first of all i'd like to apologize if my problem seems to broad to answer but i'm really getting frustrated over this. so i'm a wordpress developer mainly (used to be a front end developer) and i'm getting into python django. but after taking many courses i can't seem to understand how to do the content management aspect of my project. so here is a rundown of my problem

- in wordpress there is this concept of custom post meta where you can put fields that can change the heading of pages and fully customize the website so that the client won't need me every time he needs to change anything (CMS basically)
- now i can't even begin to imagine how to go about doing something like that for django
- i've tried putting a custom form on top of my list view in the admin page but that doesn't look so good and what if i need to customize a page that doesn't belong to a module with a list view
- i've tried to make an app and call it page but then what about the stuff that is directly related to a module.
- so my question is: how should i think about this since i don't want to go a long way in one direction just to discover that that is a poor way of doing things
- also as a side note the site i'm creating is not that much bigger than a blog which i know i'd be better off doing in wordpress anyway but i thought it would be a good starting point to familiarize my self with django.

finally if you'd recommend any courses or maybe a tutorial i'd be more than grateful.

Comment: Have you tried the getting started guide for CMS? http://support.divio.com/academy/getting-started/get-started-with-django-cms

Comment: First thing is that Django is not a CMS, it is not fair to compare Django and Wordpress.

Comment: Markwalker_ I've heared of django cms but I'm worried that the same limitations that made me think of leaving WordPress would be the same there.. Mainly would it put limitations on how big a site can be or how complicated it can get... Am I wrong

Comment: Tim yes I understand but im not looking into make a whole new cms like WordPress im just looking for a way to customize titles and maybe the ability to view mail submitions thats as much as I want

Comment: @markwalker_ has that getting started guide been moved. The documentation for this (Django CMS) seems patchy and ambiguous at times.

Comment: @PaulaLivingstone Yeah that's not there anymore, and I don't remember what it was. There's getting started type docs on the following link (and yes, the docs aren't great. If you find something out that's not well documented it's often best to update them & submit a PR)
https://docs.divio.com/en/latest/how-to/

Comment: Thanks @markwalker_. Appreciate you getting back to me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, that is a very broad question. Here is a broad answer that I hope will help.
Django is a programming "framework" that can be used to develop new web-apps, including new CMS's. In my experience, the customizability of web-page titles in a new Django-app would involve using Django's html template language with template-tags and context-variables etc, as well as Python programming within the Django framework. For doing content management, you would basically have to program your own models & functions for that, along with whatever default or other database system (MySQL, PostgreSQL) you choose to install... There is a learning curve, but Python and Django are considered by some to be among the easiest language+frameworks to learn.

[This tutorial playlist may help you.](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL4cUxeGkcC9ib4HsrXEYpQnTOTZE1x0uc) It helped me muddle thru Django in the beginning, and he has [Python tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL4cUxeGkcC9idu6GZ8EU_5B6WpKTdYZbK) also.

Comment: Thank you for the playlist this seems like a good one that I haven't seen before.. Maybe you're right maybe its just a little bit too early for me I'll have to investigate further